# How to select multiple columns from a different table using two different ids?

Tags: mysql, sql

For a project, I have to find all messages a specific person has sent. So, say I have these tables:

**person**

```
person_id | first_name | last_name
```

**message**

```
message_id | sender_id | receiver_id | message
```

Both sender_id and receiver_id reference person_id. I have to display sender's first and last name, reciever's first and last name, and message. I'm specifically having trouble displaying sender's names and receivers's names.

I've tried a variety of searches for my problem but nothing seems to work or really relate to my problem. I've seen some solutions use UNION but I have not learned that in my class yet. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT p.first_name AS "Sender First Name",
    p.last_name AS "Sender Last Name",
    p.first_name AS "Reciever First Name",
    p.last_name AS "Reciever Last Name",
    m.message_id AS "Message ID",
    m.message AS "Message",
    m.send_datetime AS "Message Timestamp"
FROM message m, person p
WHERE m.sender_id = 1
AND m.sender_id = p.person_id;
```

That gives me:

```
+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Sender First Name | Sender Last Name | Reciever First Name | Reciever Last Name | Message ID | Message                                    | Message Timestamp   |
+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Michael           | Phelps           | Michael             | Phelps             |          1 | Congrats on winning the 800m Freestyle!    | 2016-12-25 09:00:00 |
| Michael           | Phelps           | Michael             | Phelps             |          4 | Thanks!  You're the greatest sprinter ever | 2016-12-25 09:04:00 |
| Michael           | Phelps           | Michael             | Phelps             |          5 | Good luck on your race                     | 2016-12-25 09:05:00 |
+-------------------+------------------+---------------------+--------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

So sender's names are correct but receiver's are not. If I change the last line to

```
AND m.receiver_id = p.person_id;
```

then I get the correct receiever names but not the correct sender names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need two joins.  And that is `JOIN`!

```
SELECT ps.first_name AS "Sender First Name",
       ps.last_name AS "Sender Last Name",
       pr.first_name AS "Receiver First Name",
       pr.last_name AS "Receiver Last Name",
       m.message_id AS "Message ID",
       m.message AS "Message",
       m.send_datetime AS "Message Timestamp"
FROM message m JOIN
     person ps
     ON m.sender_id = ps.person_id JOIN
     person pr
     ON m.receiver_id = pr.person_id
WHERE m.sender_id = 1;
```

Notes:

- If you are learning SQL, you should be *not* be learning to use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Note that you need to use table aliases in this case, because you have a table twice in the `FROM`.
- If either column might be `NULL`, then use `LEFT JOIN`, instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: I would recommend using the even more explicit forms ` INNER JOIN` syntax since it makes it easier to picture, specially when using the popular join bubble diagram.

Answer (score 0):

do left join and use persion table alias for join with senderid and receiver id

```
p.first_name AS "Sender First Name",
p.last_name AS "Sender Last Name",
p2.first_name AS "Reciever First Name",
p2.last_name AS "Reciever Last Name",
m.message_id AS "Message ID",
m.message AS "Message",
m.send_datetime AS "Message Timestamp"
from message m left join
 person p 
on p.persionid=m.sender_id
left join person p2 on p2.persionid=m.receiver_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use inner join

For example :

```
Select *
From table1 inner join table2 On tbale1.id=table2.id
```

Best way for create innerjoin use edite query in SSMS application.